# Rails save massive hash data to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a `Hash` with 2M data. I need to transfer all data from `hash` to `database`. Hash keys fit with database columns.

I'm not sure the way I use below is the best way.

```
# users is a hash with 2M data.
users.each do |u|
   user = User.new(u)
   user.save!
end
```

what is the best way to iterate through this kind of massive data with Rails?

Comment: Have you considered converting the hash to a bunch of SQL INSERTs and bypassing ActiveRecord completely? You'd want to wrap the overall INSERT in a few transactions to make it go faster and you'd have manually apply any `User` hooks to the data first.

Comment: @muistooshort how can I put your idea to code?

Answer (score 1):

[`ActiveRecord.create`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods.html#method-i-create) accepts hashes too. Therefore I would just try:

```
User.create(users)
```

2M might be a bit too big and you might need to work in batches. But I suggest this to be faster than one insert per record.

Comment: If you're really in a bind, never underestimate the power of direct-loading into the database. MySQL's `LOAD DATA INFILE` for example is super fast.

Answer (score 1):

Try using active record import gem(https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import#hashes). You can even insert records with batching(https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import#batching)

```
User.import(users, batch_size: 1000)
```

Comment: `activerecord-import` gem is still better solution for this!