# How to save massive data to database from a web scraper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, nokogiri

I am scraping a web page that contains 2M of data by scrolling the page with Watir than getting data with Nokogiri. I can get all the data with one request.

I need to save all data to the database. I want to know which way is the fastest way to do this.

Should I make an `each` like:

```
users = doc.css('div.container > div ')
users.each do |a|
   User.name = a.css('p.name').text
   User.age  = a.css('p.surname').text
   User.save!
end
```

or first, store the data in a hash than save to database?

```
users = doc.css('div.container > div ')
user = []
users.each do |a|
  user <<  {
    name = a.css('p.name').text
    age  = a.css('p.surname').text
  }
end

User.create(user)
# User.import(users, batch_size: 1000) -> i can use batching
```

Should I save it directly to the database or use a hash? Or is there a better way?

Comment: Didn't you ask the same question yesterday ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57596533/rails-save-massive-hash-data-to-database

Comment: Please read the question again. Questions are different.

Comment: Well that's technically true, last question was about the best way and this one is about the fastest. But I'm pretty sure you got your answer last time, the fastest way is definitely to insert it directly into the database.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But directly saving to db is saving data to database for each nokogiri selection. It means for every item it will use nokogiri selection than save. Isn’t it faster to put all data to hash first than save them to database.

Comment: The best answer is to use one of the various benchmarking gems, generate some sample data that mimics what you anticipate, then write the code to test both ways. Ruby comes with the Benchmark module and there's a gem called Fruity that works very well. Either are very useful tools and allow you to find out for yourself in the system you're building.

Answer (score 1):

Use ActiveRecord Import gem to store massive data it's faster

> https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import

Comment: Using hash or directly to database ?

Comment: You can use any of array and hash procedure. With this gem both will take same time

Comment: The fastest way is to use raw data (array or hash), not objects. Check out documentation here: https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import#columns-and-arrays.

Comment: The raw data is coming from nokogiri. Should I pass data to a hash than save to the database. Or directly save to database without using hash?

Comment: users.each do |a|
  user << User.new(name: a.css('p.name').text, age: a.css('p.surname').text)
end
User.import user